# Can assembly name and it's file name be different?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

We are following `CompanyName.ProductName.LibraryName` format as our Assembly files naming convention. But when comes to Windows applications, the output exe file in the above mentioned format looks so odd, it looks something like this: `Company.Product.Library.exe`. I prefer to have this as just `Library.exe`

Is it possible to have desired executable file name without changing it's assembly name?

Comment: This is possible for sure with .NET Fx because we have such a sample assembly in our test base (since we build a tool to analyze .NET code). However we didn't build it, and I don't know how to do compile such asm, I didn't find a csc.exe compiler option specific to assembly name. My guess on .NET Core is that it is not possible on this platform to obtain such assembly because target fx directory (like /net5.0) became the rule which means less reason to rename an assembly file to add it the target fx.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this project's properties and change "Assembly name>>Application" tab

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am already aware of this setting. It may sound silly, but I just to want to know, Is "assembly name" = "file name"? Please re-read my question.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET framework, based on the official documentation, the answers is: it **depends** on where you deploy the assembly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/names

> In .NET Framework, if you put a strong-named assembly in the global assembly cache, the assembly's file name must match the assembly name, not including the file name extension, such as .exe or .dll. For example, if the file name of an assembly is myAssembly.dll, the assembly name must be myAssembly. Private assemblies deployed only in the root application directory can have an assembly name that is different from the file name.

Answer (score 0):

They are two difference concepts, and if they don't match bad things can happen.

With a net7.0 project with a CSPROJ `<Reference>` to the DLL, the build worked fine. But I got a FileNotFoundException when the app started and failed to load the library. (The DLL was compiled from CIL assembly using `ilasm` tool with line `.assembly A` but that didn't match the file name.)

I could see in procmon that dotnet tried to load A.exe and A.dll ...so in my build script I renamed the file name to match the assembly name and the FileNotFoundException went away.

Maybe using an assembly strong name would have allowed the names to be different, but I didn't want to go down that route for an open-source project.